# JPanel and JButton

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton

I'm doing a little program for me, with NetBeans. I need no create many JButtons on a JPanel but i can't do it. The JPanel has been generated by the NetBeans editor on a JFrame (also made it by the NetBeans editor)

This is the code:

```
public static ArrayList<Account> accounts = Account.accounts;
public verCuenta() {
    initComponents();
    panel.setVisible(true);
    Account ac;
    JButton button;

    int size= accounts.size();

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        button = new JButton(accounts.get(i).getName());
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(null);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,30));
        panel.add(button);
    }
```

Comment: Change the layout manager, have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Even with this help i can't solve the problem... I mean... The JButton can't be printed on a JPanel?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that `panel` has been added to what ever container you're trying to show it on. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a single Button to pop up,
maybe start with this first, then try to get several, then get your loop working

```
// Create a new button:
JButton b1 = new JButton("ok");
// Set the location and size of the button:
b1.setSize(100, 26);
// Add the button to the window:
jPanel1.add(b1);
//Repaint the Panel to make visible
jPanel1.repaint();
```

It only works when you set a size, just checked in Netbeans.
You can also specify the location, using

```
b1.setLocation(100, 100);
```

btw, whole frame is in gridbag layout

Answer (score -1):

you need to add all elements to the panel and then call the `setVisible` method.

Additions after calling the `setVisible` method are not per se taking into account.